# Java - Why do I get null when I try to 9999999999999 into a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Here's my code:

```
String value = "9999999999999";
Character decimalFormat = '.';
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(decimalFormat);
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(decimalFormat.equals('.') ? ',' : '.');
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) format.parse(value, parsePosition);
```

When I pass 9999999999999 or 999999999999.999999999 as a "value" into that code I get null.  Why?

Comment: What is the value of decimalFormat?

Comment: Where are you getting null? If you print out the result object doesn't it give you the right value?

Comment: I get: result = null

Comment: Maybe you have some space in your value String?

Comment: no, there are no spaces in the value

Comment: I pasted code (revision 2), and it worked fine. Adding a print at the end printed `9999999999999`.

Comment: I doesn't for me, but actually when I removed parsePosition I got the 9999999999999 back as a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

**1 It works perfectly**, and even if you put *bad* number with letters inside, you get the begining.

**2 except if your string begin with a letter**: X999 gives you null, **or is void.**

**3A So I suspect there is another code which modifies value.**

or

**3B You don't use normal libraries (import java.text...)**

**4 Last method: trace every call.**

what parse does:

The method attempts to parse text starting at the index given by pos. If parsing succeeds, then the index of pos is updated to the index after the last character used (parsing does not necessarily use all characters up to the end of the string), and the parsed number is returned. The updated pos can be used to indicate the starting point for the next call to this method. If an error occurs, then the index of pos is not changed, the error index of pos is set to the index of the character where the error occurred, and null is returned.